Middleware misbehaving after build but working properly in devlopment mode in Nextjs 14.1
I am working on Nextjs project of an E-commerce web app and while working in development mode middleware works perfectly, it redirects user to '/signin' if user is unauthorised or else it goes to '/account' page.
But after build it starts misbehaving, sometime it goes to '/account' if user is unauthorised.
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware (req:NextRequest){
    const path=req.nextUrl.pathname;
    const auth=req.cookies.get("at");
    const toRedir=path==="/cart"||path==="/account"||path==="/seller"||path==="/seller/addProduct";
    console.log(path);
    if (!toRedir&&auth) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/account",req.nextUrl))
    }
    if (toRedir&&!auth) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/signin",req.nextUrl));
    }
}

export const config={
    matcher:[
        "/cart",
        "/account",
        "/seller/:path*",
        "/signin",
        "/signup"
    ]
}

